# Malformed UTF-8 characters

Tags: php, javascript, jwt

Tengo el siguiente inconveniente con JWT en PHP.

Genero el token y lo guardo en localStorage (*porque de momento no encuentro una solución mejor*).

Utilizo la siguiente función:

```
static public function ctrMostrarUsuarios($item, $valor){

    $token = '<script>document.writeln(localStorage.getItem("token"));</script>'; // recupero el Token de LocalStorage
    
    ControladorUsuarios::validarToken($token);

}
```

Pero me da el siguiente error:

> Malformed UTF-8 characters.

Aunque si imprimo la variable `$token`, **la muestra correctamente**. Y si copio el valor de localstorage y se lo asigno la función validarToken , la valida bien.

Para generar el Token utilizo lo siguiente:

```
$contenidoToken = array(
    'iat' => $tiempo,
    'exp' => $tiempoLimite,
    'dataUsuario' => [
        'id' => $respuesta["id"],
        'usuario' => $respuesta["usuario"],
        'nombre' => $respuesta["nombre"] . " " . $respuesta["apellido"] ,
        'perfil' => $respuesta["perfil"],
        'app' => $GLOBALS["app"]
    ]
);

$tokenJWT = JWT::encode($contenidoToken, $GLOBALS["llave"]);

echo '<script>

localStorage.setItem("token", "' . $tokenJWT . '"); 

</script>';
```

¿Cómo puedo solucionarlo?

¡Gracias!

Comment: PHP y Javascript no se pueden comunicar de esa forma, porque se ejecutan en diferentes contextos, PHP del lado del servidor y Javascript del lado del cliente. Cuando generas esa cadena, se procesa en PHP y solo hasta que llega al navegador podría ejecutarse el código Javascript, pero, como no estás haciendo `echo`, queda simplemente como una cadena. Podrías usar variables de sesión, pero es necesario saber cómo obtienes el _token_ para guardarlo en _localStorage_; por favor edita la pregunta para agregar ese código.

Comment: Listo, ya edite la pregunta . Obtengo el JWT y lo guardo en localstorage con un echo. 
En este momento estoy usando sesiones, peor quiero dejar de usarlas por ello recurro a localstorage

Comment: Tambien aclaro que si tomo la clave guardada en localstorage y la pego asi como esta en la variable $token funciona perfectamente

Comment: Debes leer el token guardado en _localStorage_ en el navegador y después enviarlo a PHP por AJAX, no veo otra alternativa. ¿Por qué quieres dejar de usar sesiones?

Comment: Me parece mala practita hacerlo. no crees ? estaria remplazando las sesiones por JWT y ademas no siempre puedes controlar el tiempo de caducidad de las sessiones facilmente( es decir no siempre se puede editar el php.ini) por eso lo suplantaria completamente con JWT

Comment: PHP no tiene acceso al localstorage del navegador. Sería una vulnerabilidad crítica. Lo que se hace es enviar el jwt en el header Authorization o el X-Access-Token anteponiendo  `Bearer` . Del lado del servidor tu validación ocurre en un Middleware, no en el controller

Comment: Y donde creen que es más conveniente guardarla ? Gracias !